# define a measure on A the power set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was asked the following:

Let $X$ be any set and $A = P(X)$ be the power set of $X$. Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be distinct points in $X$ and let $α_1, \ldots , α_n$ be positive real numbers, define the measure on A:

Am I correct in saying:

$μ = α_1δx_1 + α_2δx_2 + \cdots + α_nδx_n$ defines a measure on $A$?

Comment: Yes, your $\mu$ is a measure on the power set.

Comment: Thank you ! Is this always a probability measure? I know You can always define certain measures on the whole power set, for example the dirac measure δx(A)=1
δ
x
(
A
)
=
1
 if x∈A
x
∈
A
 and δx(A)=0
δ
x
(
A
)
=
0
 otherwise.

Also, countable sums of Diracs work well. On a countable sample space, any measure is of this form (countable linear combination if Diracs).

Only when we consider more interesting measures like the Lebesgue measure, we can't define it on the whole powerset while maintaining desired properties like translation invariance. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: It is  a probablity measure if $\alpha_k$'s add up to $1$.

Comment: Okay I see! Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy